# How to display message just one time When Timer reaches 15 sec

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to display a text message `Time is up` only once when Java Timer reaches 15 seconds but it is being displayed every 15 seconds.What am I doing wrong ?

### Code:

```
package testovi;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Test extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Timer time;
    private JLabel vrijeme = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Blah1");
    private JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Blah2");
    private int brojac = 15;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 333);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton print = new JButton("New button");

        print.setBounds(24, 192, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(print);

        JLabel lblVrijeme = new JLabel("Vrijeme:");
        lblVrijeme.setBounds(182, 196, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblVrijeme);

        vrijeme.setBounds(245, 191, 26, 24);
        contentPane.add(vrijeme);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                startajBrojac();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(22, 226, 105, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        l1.setBounds(182, 230, 89, 19);
        contentPane.add(l1);

        l2.setBounds(182, 260, 89, 19);
        contentPane.add(l2);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Test.class.getResource("/testovi/slike/sat.png")));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(225, 173, 60, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        l1.addMouseListener(this);
        l2.addMouseListener(this);

        // Akciski listener za tajmer
        time = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vrijeme.setText(String.valueOf(brojac));
                brojac--;
                if (brojac == -1) {
                    time.stop();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Test(), "Time is  up");
                }
            }
        });
        time.start();

    }

    private void startajBrojac() {
        brojac = 15;
        time.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == l1) {

            startajBrojac();
        } else if (e.getSource() == l2) {
            startajBrojac();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: write your code in english. We don't know what "brojac" or "vrijeme" is. Writing in english would make it easier to read. Also try to post only as much code as needed to get the point of your question.

Comment: I see you've asked quite a few questions already, but you never accepted or voted for any answer. If you want to keep getting answers, you should start accepting answers that helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you show the "Time is up" dialog, you create a new `Test` frame as the parent of that dialogue. The frame is not shown, because `setVisible` is not called, but with the frame, a new timer thread is created, starting the countdown again. You should use the existing frame instead.

Change this line

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Test() "Time is  up");
```

to this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Test.this, "Time is  up");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer(15000, listener);
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

You could have found that yourself, simply by reading the [api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Comment: I think he needs the `1000` interval for the countdown (`vrijeme.setText(String.valueOf(brojac));`)...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.setRepeats()`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(15000, new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Comment: OP needs the 1 second interval for the countdown. Also, this does not solve the actual problem.